# How do I populate Select Options from Redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-select

I am using react-select

I have a form that creates a new contact. In my redux store I have groups that are already created. When I click the Select to show the options I would like to load the options from my redux store.

The "groups" from redux store has only one value, that is title: String in the GroupModel in the backend.

I understand that react-select needs to have a label: '', value: ''

If I create an array myself and pass the values in it works fine. But with redux nothing is working. I cant find any answers anywhere online which seems trivial to me....

Here is my component below

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Select from 'react-select';
import { createContact } from '../../actions/index';
import { Button, Form, FormGroup, Input, Label } from 'reactstrap';
import Divider from '../common/Divider';

const ContactForm = ({ hasLabel }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  // State
  const [contact, setContact] = useState({ 
    group: '',
})
  
  // Submit Handler
   const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    dispatch(createContact(contact))
   };

  // Change Handler
  const handleChange = e => {
    setContact({...contact, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
  };
  
  // bringing in our state from redux
  const groups = useSelector((state) => state.groups)
  

  return ( 
  <>
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <FormGroup>
        <Label>
          Choose Group/List</Label>
            <Select
              name="group"
              options={groups}
              getOptionlabel={({title}) => title}
              getOptionValue={({_id}) => _id }
              onChange={() => {}}
              isMulti
            />
        </FormGroup>
      </div>
    </Form>
  </>
  );
};

ContactForm.propTypes = {
  
  hasLabel: PropTypes.bool
};

ContactForm.defaultProps = {
  layout: 'basic',
  hasLabel: false
};

export default ContactForm;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.... So my solution above was pretty much correct. The issue I had was the getOptionlabel needed to be getOptionLabel <--- notice I forgot to capitalize the L in label....

I hope someone who needs to use react-select with redux finds this post and it helps.

So basically just bring in your redux state with useSelector or connect,
then make sure to use the props below in your Select component

```
getOptionLabel={({title}) => title}
getOptionValue={({_id}) => _id}
```